# Yahoo Pipes: filter items in a feed based on words in a text file

Tags: yahoo, yahoo-pipes, yql, graphical-programming, graphical-language

I have a pipe that filters an RSS feed and removes any item that contains "stopwords" that I've chosen. Currently I've manually created a filter for each stopword in the pipe editor, but the more logical way is to read these from a file. I've figured out how to read the stopwords out of the text file, but how do I apply the filter operator to the feed, once for every stopword?

The documentation [states explicitly](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/docs?doc=operators#Loop) that operators can't be applied within the loop construct, but hopefully I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 3):

You're not missing anything - the filter operator can't go in a loop.

Your best bet might be to generate a regex out of the stopwords and filter using that. e.g. generate a string like `(word1|word2|word3|...|wordN)`.

You may have to escape any odd characters. Also I'm not sure how long a regex can be so you might have to chunk it over multiple filter rules.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Gavin Brock's answer the following Yahoo Pipes
filters the feed items (title, description, link and author) according to multiple stopwords:

- [Pipes Info](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=1698e7f0447e80417b376469b3f00937)
- [Pipes Edit](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.edit?_id=1698e7f0447e80417b376469b3f00937)
- [Pipes Demo](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=1698e7f0447e80417b376469b3f00937&_render=rss&feed=http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss&stopwords=Amnesty-rio-food-maya-could)

**Inputs**

- _render=rss
- feed=http://example.com/feed.rss
- stopwords=word1-word2-word3