# Using Yahoo Pipes to filter tweets

Tags: twitter, feed, yahoo-pipes, atom-feed

I am trying to create a yahoo pipe that takes ideally takes all tweets tweeted at any point in time and filters down by a number of attributes to then display a filtered feed.

Basically in order this is what I want to happen:

1. Get a feed of all tweets at any one time.
2. Filter tweets by geolocation origin, i.e. UK,
3. Filter by a number of of different combinations of keywords.
4. Output as an RSS feed (though this isn't really the crucial stage as Yahoo Pipes takes care of this anyway)

Disclaimer: of course I understand that there are limits to the amount of tweets that could come through etc but I would like to cast the input net as wide as possible.

I have managed to get stages 3 & 4 working correctly and for the time being I am not really worrying about step 2 (although if you have any suggestions I am all ears), but stages 1 is where I am struggling. What I have attempted is using a Fetch Feed module with the URL - http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=lang:en - however it seems that this only pulls 15 tweets. Is there any way that I can pull more than 15 tweets every time the pipe is run, otherwise I think this may all be in vain.

FYI, here is the link to the pipe as it stands - http://pipes.yahoo.com/ludus247/182ef4a83885698428d57865da5cf85b

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't do what you want to do, it requires you to use [the streaming API for a firehose](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/firehose) which requires special permission.  Also, it's a push model, not a pull model, and more than likely, you won't be able to keep up with the traffic.

Comment: Ah fair enough. Is there a URL etc that I can use in order to develop a proof of concept that delivers a lot more than 15 tweets? As you can probably tell I am not a developer and am quite unfamiliar with the Twitter API.

Comment: Check the other type of calls at the link I provided.  You can perform a filtered search which will stream tweets as they come to you.  Store the tweets in a database and then generate your RSS feed off that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Yahoo Pipes: filter items in a feed based on words in a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693673/yahoo-pipes-filter-items-in-a-feed-based-on-words-in-a-text-file)